# bootstrap 5 space-between misaligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5, horizontal-alignment

I have some HTML/CSS where I am trying to make use of Bootstrap 5.2 and `justify-content-between` to push 2 buttons out to the edges of the container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-grey">
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-2 text-start">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">LEFT</button>    
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 text-end">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">RIGHT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look - with the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` buttons aligned to the edges.

[image]

It's fine until the viewport reaches anything under 768px wide (sm or xs), at which point the `RIGHT` button sticks out.

[image]

I can tweak the margin at the relevant responsive break points but it seems like I've got something wrong and shouldn't have to do that.

Is there a correct / better way to achieve this?

Comment: thanks - alignment is only correct for `sm` now though...

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment. Apparently, it is allowed to have more than 12 columns per row. I've had that misconception for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your second attempt, you had rows inside of rows. The `row`s need to be direct children of the `container`.

I'd probably just use some explicit flex boxes here if you don't need the column collapsing provided by Bootstrap grids:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <ul style='background:grey' class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-grey">
              <li>Test</li>
            </ul> 
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">LEFT</button> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">RIGHT</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A flex-box column to stack them, then a flex-box row for the buttons. The current `.container` element isn't really necessary, but it maintains the padding you had.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-dark">
        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col text-start">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">LEFT</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-end">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">RIGHT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```